# Exclude a page from indexing on a per page basis

Tags: search

I would like to be able to remove a page from search engines (external and drupal). I want to add a checkbox on the content type to be able to specify which page should or should not be indexed.

My plan is to check via the hook_node_save if the checkbox is checked, and if so, edit the robots.txt to add a Disallow via the provided url. If the box is unchecked, I remove it from the robots.txt

This is complicated though. Does anyone has a better solution ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. Once installed you will have a checkbox: **Prevent search engines from indexing this page** located on every node under Meta tags -> Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  the [noindex module](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_noindex). It should allow you to do what you want.

That is per-page configuration of indexing via the "robots" meta tag.